# For loop generates no output nor errors

Tags: string-manipulation

I have the below For loop to generate Histograms for 16 values in my dataset but I have no historgam showing. What may I be doing wrong?

```
 For[i = 1, i < 17, i++,
  mycnr = StringJoin["CNR", ToString[i]];
  cnr[i] = newDataSet[All, mycnr];
  Histogram[cnr[i]]]
```

when I comment out lines 3 and 4 inside for loop to see the outcome of the StringJoin function, I do not see the mycnr simply showing the CNR1 to CNR16 I expect from such StringJoin

I apologize, I am new at Mathematica, so "be gentle" :-)

Comment: Try `Print`ing the `Histogram`s.

Comment: Provide a sample of the first few rows of `newDataSet`.

Comment: use `Table` instead of `For`.  (and read this.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/2079)

Comment: See specifically: [(124077)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124077/121)

Comment: You should also read up on `Dataset` as you are missing out on some powerful functionality.  Consider `ds = AssociationThread[{"A1", "A2", "A3"}, #] & /@  RandomInteger[{3, 15}, {20, 3}] // Dataset; dsCharts = 
  ds[Transpose /* Map[Histogram], {"A1", "A2"}]; dsCharts` Then `dsCharts["A1"]`

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have much to learn. Print worked very well and fixed teh instability of the statement. Sometimes it worked fine, then as I added other code it broke again, but with Print, it stabilize it.

Answer (score -1):

I simplified it and finally got it to work:

```
For[i = 1, i < 17, i++, 
  Histogram[newDataSet[All, StringJoin["CNR", ToString[i]]]]
];
```